# C# Selenium: Wait until dropdown loads/shows value?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have a program in VS using C# with Selenium that inputs data into a dropdown textbox.

But the program gets an error because it takes a long time to show the value before it clicks Enter.

I'm also using ElementExists, ElementVisible, ElementClickable methods.

**Is there a way to wait until the dropdown shows the value before it clicks Enter?**(Is there a way to wait until the dropdown loads?)

I also increased the duration of Thread.Sleep but it's too inconsistent.

Appreciate if you could help me out. Thanks in advance.

```
var dropDown= wDriver.FindElements(By.XPath("//input[contains(@aria, 'false')and not(@class)]"));

dropDown.SendKeys(value);

Thread.Sleep(2000);

dropDown.SendKeys(Keys.Enter);
```

NOTE: (I'm not using SelectElement because the dropdown element can only be access thru Xpath.)

Comment: Please add  the HTML code of your dropdown to the question.

Comment: The use of `SelectElement` has nothing to do with how the element is found, XPath or otherwise. You can use `SelectElement dropdown = new SelectElement(driver.FindElement(By.XPath("")));`.

Comment: Why are you sending ENTER to a dropdown? Why are you using `.SendKeys()` with a dropdown at all? If it's not truly a `SELECT` element, you should be using `click()` instead. Please try some of these suggestions and update your question with the code you tried and the results, including any error messages, etc.

Answer (score 0):

have you checked for waitForElementPresent command.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//input[contains(@aria, 'false')and not(@class)]")));
```

or you can use wait untill expected condition.

```
wait.until(
    ExpectedConditions.presenceOfNestedElementsLocatedBy(By.xpath(<"//input[contains(@aria, 'false')and not(@class)]">), By.tagName("input"))
)
```